# Prevent OneDrive from re-syncing everything after re-installing Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

The context is almost identical to that of [Windows 8.1 move OneDrive to existing folder after OS reinstall](https://superuser.com/q/834667/688600), except I'm on Windows 10. I want to stop OneDrive from re-syncing everything after re-installing Windows 10 because the files are BIG and remain intact before and after OS reinstallation. Even the paths remain the same before and after (is still `D:\OneDrive` on my machine - the D drive is the same volume).

I have searched on Google and found results like [this](https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive-archive/suggestions/8187195-don-t-re-download-existing-files-on-windows-10-one) or [this](http://www.tenforums.com/installation-setup/7057-how-migrate-files-without-confusing-one-drive.html), and no definitive answer was found.

Is there a solution for W10?

Answer (score 0):

**Note** first: I haven't tried it myself. Please comment if you find this working or not working.

**Based on my observation** and miscellaneous pieces of information found online, I figured out this *potential* solution.

Before wiping out the old system, back up `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\OneDrive\settings` (which usually expands to `C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\settings`).

After re-installing Windows 10, sign in to your Microsoft Account, and set up OneDrive as usual, including switching to the target location if it isn't the default (`%UserProfile%\OneDrive`). After setting up OneDrive in the newly-installed Windows 10, it should start "looking for changes". Exit OneDrive at this point. Navigate to the same path in the new system, delete the `settings` folder and restore contents from the backup from the old system. Reboot the system.

To maximize chance of success, I recommend that you keep your previous OneDrive location unchanged. That says, it's better to keep the OneDrive folder at the same path, like `D:\OneDrive` for me. This primarily includes re-assigning the same drive letter to the same volume on your machine.